# Summing and comparing with or without parentheses

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 columns which are of type `double`.

I need to get results where the sum these of 3 columns is more than x.

Maybe a dumb question, which of the following methods is better for this

1) Usually summing: `WHERE col1 + col2 + col3 > x`

2) Or summing in parentheses: `WHERE (col1 + col2 + col3) > x`

Or there is absolutely no difference between the two menthods ?

Comment: Normalization anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your both query has no problem.By operator hierarchies it would be better to use parenthesis method.

[MySQL Operator Precedence documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operator-precedence.html)

> Operator precedences are shown in the following list, from highest
>   precedence to the lowest. Operators that are shown together on a line
>   have the same precedence.
>
> ```
> INTERVAL
> BINARY, COLLATE
> !
> - (unary minus), ~ (unary bit inversion)
> ^
> *, /, DIV, %, MOD
> -, +
> <<, >>
> &
> |
> = (comparison), <=>, >=, >, <=, <, <>, !=, IS, LIKE, REGEXP, IN
> BETWEEN, CASE, WHEN, THEN, ELSE
> NOT
> &&, AND
> XOR
> ||, OR
> = (assignment), := 
> Its better to handle the summarized values among three columns.
> ```

`WHERE (col1 + col2 + col3) > x`